# Extend object with values from parent

Tags: c#, oop, inheritance

Let's say I've got a class:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}
```

and in some function I'm getting the list of objects type Parent, next I'd like to extend those objects with new field with some value, so I'm declaring an extended class like this:

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(Parent parent)
    {
        Name = parent.Name;
        City = parent.City;
    }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

and call the costructor for each extended object. Is there a better way to do that? What if there will be multiple properties in Parent? Maybe there is some more elegant way to achieve that?

Comment: Is there a reason you're bothering with a transfer of data from one class to another instead of going straight to `Child` in the first place?

Comment: Why does `Child` extend `Parent`? Is a child really also a parent? (Obviously that's possible, but it doesn't feel right in this context). Should `Child` instead have a `Parent` property?

Comment: The motivation to this question is a situation in where I'm getting a list of objects with data, and want to show this data but with some additional fields, without touching the base class.

Comment: @SteveMacculan: Without touching the base class or the instance? My question is about usage. Why load into `Parent` only to transfer into `Child`? Are you doing something separate with `Parent` that `Child` can't (or shouldn't) accommodate? My question is obviously moot since you've accepted an answer, but it goes towards the selection of a proper design pattern.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think maybe you're looking for a copy-constructor pattern. Each level defines a `protected` constructor which copies the relevant properties:

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    //normal constructor
    public Parent()
    {

    }

    protected Parent(Parent copy)
    {
        this.Name = copy.Name;
        this.City = copy.City;
    }
}
```

The `Child` would inherit from `Parent`, pass it down through to the copy-constructor, then append its new values as desired:

```
public class Child : Parent
{
    public string NewInfo { get; set; }

    public Child(Parent copy)
        : base(copy)
    {

    }
}
```

Usage might look like:

```
Parent parent = new Parent() { Name = "Name", City = "StackOverflow"};

Child child = new Child(parent) { NewInfo = "Something new!" };

Console.WriteLine(child.Name); //Name
Console.WriteLine(child.City); //StackOverflow
Console.WriteLine(child.NewInfo); //Something new!
```

The benefit from this is that you can have multiple levels of inheritance with each level managing their own properties.

EDIT: Given your most recent comment:

> The motivation to this question is a situation in where I'm getting a
>   list of objects with data, and want to show this data but with some
>   additional fields, without touching the base class.

Perhaps the better method then is to wrap the base class:

```
public class Child
{
    private readonly Parent WrappedParent;

    public string NewInfo { get; set; }

    public string Name 
    { 
        get { return WrappedParent.Name; }
        set { WrappedParent.Name = value; }
    }

    public string City 
    { 
        get { return WrappedParent.City; }
        set { WrappedParent.City = value; }
    }

    public Child(Parent wrappedParent)
    {
        this.WrappedParent = wrappedParent; 
    }
}
```

Downside is you have to redeclare each property, and you are no longer inheriting (cannot be considered a) `"Parent"`, but then you are definitly "not touching" the base class anymore. Could move the "Parent" properties into an `IParent` interface if that's better for you, but doing so again is "touching" the base class as you'll have to add the `IParent` interface declaration to its class definition.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if I got you wrong, but this could be a more standar solution

```
public class Parent
{
    public Parent(string name, string city)
    {
       Name = name;
       City = city;
    }

    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(string name, string city, int age) : base(name, city)
    {
       Age = age;
    }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This works, and it's suitable for objects with relatively few properties, but it becomes cumbersome when their are numerous properties.

Comment: This does not answer the question, it is a demonstration of basic class extension.  The original question asks for the newly created Child object to reflect the _current_ fields and properties of an existing Parent object.  As in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
public class Parent
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string City { get; set; }

    public Parent(string name, string city)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.City = city;
    }

    public Parent():this(string.Empty, string.Empty)
    {
    }
}

public class Child : Parent
{
    public Child(Parent parent, int age):base(parent.Name, parent.City)
    {
        this.Age = age;
    }

    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: This was not copy & paste, we post almost the same time.

Answer (score 0):

In a recent version of Visual Studio (VS Community Edition 2019), I was able to type this:

```
internal class Child : IParent
{
    private IParent parent;
    public ChildField childField;

    public Child(IParent parent, ChildField newChildField)
    {
        this.parent = parent;
        this.childField = newChildField;
    }
}
```

I then mouseover `IParent` (which is showing an error message because not fully implemented), Ctrl . to solve the error, and one of the options is "**Implement interface through parent**".  Click on that option, and VS types out all the properties and methods for you, wrapping the base class.  Easy, correct and awesome.